# Existence of a graph for which all subgraph have bounded chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a $\Delta-$regular graph for which the chromatic number $\chi(G) = \Theta(\Delta / \log\Delta)$. Consider all subgraphs $G'$ of at most $n \frac{\Delta}{\Delta+1}$ nodes. Is it possible that all of them have $\chi(G') = o(\Delta/\log \Delta)$ ?

I just need to prove the existence for one $G$.  I feel like it  should be possible to prove it using a argument similar to "if it's not working for $G$, taking any $G'$ and repeat until it's working" but I cannot wrap my head around it.

Comment: We can't talk about asymptotic bounds for just one $G$ and $\Delta$. There should be an infinite sequence of $(G, \Delta)$ to talk about asymptotic of $\chi(G)$ and $\chi(G')$

Comment: I have a proof that makes the problem quite trivial. I'm fairly sure I'm missing something, but I can't find a problem with my solution, so I'll post it. I assume the intended method is probably some sort of probabilistic argument...

Comment: Scratch that -- I just realized that I don't know that $\Theta(\Delta / \log\Delta)$ means. Is $\Delta$ increasing with the sequence? Otherwise if $\Delta / \log\Delta$ is a constant it doesn't make sense to consider asymptotics.

Comment: @koifish In my line of work we are interested with graphs with such chromatic number.  I thought at first it was not relevant at first but the minimal cycle length is also $\Theta(\Delta/\log \Delta$ on such graphs.